# How to correctly perform a future on a FirebaseQuery using FirebaseAnimatedList in Flutter?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, async-await, dart, future, flutter

My FirebaseQuery is not correctly awaiting for information when I initially view the FirebaseAnimatedList.  Once I leave the page and come back everything's as expected. Here is my code...

```
var fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

var allUsers = FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child('users')
    .orderByChild('displayName');

@override
  Future <Null> _getFriends(value) async {
    try {
      Map myMap = await value; //store each map
      String n;
      String p;

      var titles = await myMap.values;
      for (var items in titles) {
        n = (items['displayName']);
        p = (items['photo']);
      }
      await name.add(n);
      await photos.add(p);
    } catch (error) {}
  }

child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                          query: fb,
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          //sort: ,
                          reverse: false,
                          itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot usersSnap,
                              Animation<double> animation, int Index) {
                            return new StreamBuilder<Event>(
                                stream: fb
                                    .child('users')
                                    .orderByChild('displayName')
                                    .onValue,
                                builder: (BuildContext context,
                                    AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
                                  switch (event.connectionState) {
                                    case ConnectionState.none:
                                      _getFriends(event.data.snapshot.value);
                          
                                      return new InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                        onTap: null,
                                        child: new ListTile(
                                            leading: new CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundImage: new AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/placeholder.png'),
                                              radius: 35.0,
                                            ),
                                            title: new Text(name[Index],
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                                  color: Colors.black
                                              ),)
                                        ),
                                      );
```

Comment: Why are you using animated list and stream for one query ?

Comment: Previous examples use it like this.  If there's a more efficient way please let me know.

Comment: How about not using an animated list at all and use StreamBuilder only ? I do not see the reason behind using animated list here.

Comment: You may have noticed that your animated list is doing except it is has a query on the whole database for no reason.

Comment: In your case I would just use one of them not both.

Comment: I'll try using a StreamBuilder.  I think the problem is that FirebaseAnimatedList does not allow for indexing.  If I am wrong or if there's a work around for this that doesn't need both please let me know.

Comment: @aziza I've adjusted my code.  Now I'm getting the error `getter "snapshot" was called on null`.  Any idea on how to find this type of error and present a loading message?

Comment: Both _getFriends method and AnimatedList are not needed here. You can actually use AnimatedList alone to get the exact same result you are looking for.